# Function to check if a dynamic constraint is valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, dynamic, constraints

I have a table storing some settings, with columns setName nvarchar(), setValue sql_variant, setRule nvarchar(). The settings may have different value types (hence setValue as sql_variant), and each setting has its own validation rule (setRule), e.g.: setting is integer and can be 0 to 5, therefore setRule is 'setValue between 0 and 5'; setting2 is string and should be one of the values in column Name of table Employees, therefore setRule is 'setValue in select Name from Employees'.
How can I validate the setValue's with their coresponding setRule's?

I created a procedure that builds a sql command with the setRule, then executes the sql and returns the result (1 if the rule validates, 0 if it doesn't):

```
CREATE procedure ValidSetting 
(
    @value  sql_variant,
    @rule   nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    if @rule is null
        return 1
    else
        begin
            set @rule = replace(@rule, 'setValue', cast(@value as nvarchar(max)))   -- in the rule, replace 'setValue' with its actual value

            DECLARE @sql    nvarchar(MAX),  
                    @params nvarchar(4000),
                    @Result bit
            set @sql = N'SELECT @check = case when (' + @rule + ') then 1 else 0 end'
            set @params = N'@check  int OUTPUT'
            DECLARE @check  int
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @check OUTPUT
            set @Result = @check
        end
        return @Result
END
GO
```

It works fine in a query under SSMS:

```
declare @result int
exec @result = dbo.CheckSetting 1,'setValue in (0,1)'
select @result
```

returns 1,
but if I try to use it in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckSetting 
(
    @value  sql_variant,
    @rule   nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result int
    exec @result = dbo.ValidSetting @value,@rule
    return @result
END
GO
```

it fails when running the function:
`select dbo.ChekSetting(1,'setValue in (0,1)')`
returns error message 'Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.'
I understand the meaning of the message, but how can I achieve what I need? It's already 2 days since I'm struggling with this (I'm a beginner in T-SQL, so please bear with me)